# Why data from parent directive doesn't pass to child directive

Tags: angularjs

I have pretty simple code

```
<body ng-app="app">
<outer>
    <inner param="vm.test" param2="vm.test2"></inner>
</outer>
</body
```

my directives and controllers looks like

```
    function outerCtrl() {
        this.test = 'First test';
        this.test2 = 'Second Test';
    }

    function innerCtrl() {}

    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('OuterCtrl', outerCtrl)
        .directive('outer', function() {
            return {
                // scope: {},
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                template: "<div>I'm the outer part <br/> <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>",
                controller: "OuterCtrl as vm",
                bindToController: true
            }
        })
        .controller('InnerCtrl', innerCtrl)
        .directive('inner', function() {
            return {
                scope: {},
                require: '^^outer',
                restrict: 'E',
                template: "I'm the inner part - {{vm.param}} and {{vm.param2}}",
                controller: "InnerCtrl as vm",
                bindToController: {
                    param: '=',
                    param2: '='
                }
            }
        });
```

And actually it works. But it's get broken when I define the isolated scope for outer directive (if I just uncomment scope definition for outer directive)
How to fix this?

https://codepen.io/ponomarev_aleksandr/pen/ypQymP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it is not working:**

In your working example you don't pass data from the parent directive to the child. Since your *outer* directive has `scope:false` by default, it doesn't create an own scope, hence it is in the outer scope (in a root scope in this case) and `OuterCtrl` is in the root scope as `vm` property. So actually you pass data from the root scope to `inner` directive.

When you uncomment `scope: {}` outer directive creates its own isolated scope with `vm` property and you cannot use it in outer scope (root scope). You can use it only inside `outer` directive (in its template).

**How to fix it with isolated scope:**

**1)** Probably you need to place your `inner` directive into `outer` directive template. Then you will be able to pass data from the outer directive to the inner directive.

**2)** If the first approach is not possible work with the outer scope (root scope here) from `outer` directive:

2.1) via $scope.$parent. But in most cases this is not the best approach because this code becomes fragile.

2.2) introduce additional variables in the root scope and bind them two-directional to the `outer` directive's scope variable and then pass them to `inner` directive